# django serializer is_valid() return false

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

using django 2.0.2
      Python 3.4

MySerializers.py

```
class MySerializer(BaseSerializer):
    UserUID = serializers.CharField()
    DeviceUID = serializers.CharField()
    SessionId = serializers.CharField()
```

MyView.py

```
class MyVeiw(BaseViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = MySerializer(data=request.data.dict())
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            print(serializer_class.errors)
            return Response(0)
        else:
            return Response(1)
```

input data

```
{'SessionId': '222a282f-c3f8-46d2-8476-8d4ec627a477', 'UserUID': '62', 'DeviceUI
D': '25'}
```

serializer_class

```
 return MySerializer(data={'SessionId': '7c5d0530-8e54-42aa-91a0-ce8776c82490', 'Us
erUID': '64', 'DeviceUID': '27'}):
    UserUID = CharField()
    DeviceUID = CharField()
    SessionId = CharField()
```

serializer_class.initial_data

```
return {'UserUID': '65', 'DeviceUID': '28', 'SessionId': 'aecef14f-
       7f9d-4f01-bc1d-89514  8ab0c05'}
```

serializer_class.errors

```
return {}
```

but `is_valid()` is always `false`

why errors `return empty list`

i tried  SessionId change `UUIDField()` but not work

and `UserUID` , `DeviceUID` Change `IntegerField()` but  not work

i think this serializer is valid why return false

Comment: what is your `BaseSerializer` class? if it class of drf you should to add `to_internal_value` to call `is_valid`

Comment: What is `BaseViewSet`?

Comment: Please specify the class of drf you use? I think "BaseSerializer" and "BaseViewSet" are your custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `class MySerializer(BaseSerializer):` to `class MySerializer(Serializer):`.

As Bear Brown mentioned; if you inherit from `BaseSerialzier`, you are expected to define the `to_internal_value` yourself.

By default, `BaseSerializer` raises a `NotImplementedError`:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    raise NotImplementedError('`to_internal_value()` must be implemented.')
```